# Mac Screenshot Cmd+Shift+4 no longer defaults to file save --it follows the options set in Cmd+Shift+5 instead

Tags: mac, screen-capture, copy-paste

On a MacBook Pro with Monterey 12.5

For a long time, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> would enable a custom screenshot (drag cursor) that would dump a file to the Desktop in addition to putting the image in the Clipboard.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> would dump only to the clipboard but not to a file.

The distinction between these two options was helpful when one wanted to capture as a file for perusing later vs. pasting in an application. The only requirement of the user to toggle between 1) saving a file of the screenshot and 2) putting the image only in the Clipboard was inclusion or exclusion of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in the sequence.

Since I started using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>, sometimes (a newer version of screenshot that has some nice pop-up options and features), the preference I set in there now seems to govern where my screenshots end up for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> as well?

For example, if I hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> and under **Options** select **Preview** in the **Save to** section, that becomes the new default for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> also.  Adding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to the sequence ignores the preference and just dumps to the clipboard as before (good).

I understand I can toggle these back and forth thru <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> and **Save to** options but it's an extra step.  I commonly use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> to capture to the clipboard.

I would prefer that the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> behavior would remain always saving to a file as a separate preference from <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>.

My question: do others observe this same behavior?  Any workarounds besides toggling manually between preferences in <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this is the same right back to Mojave, when it was first introduced.
Basically, you have two interfaces to the same app & prefs.

You can tweak the prefs in Terminal using `defaults write`, e.g.
`defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop && \ killall SystemUIServer`
or
`defaults write com.apple.screencapture type -string "png"`
There's a full list of commands at https://ss64.com/osx/screencapture.html

You could, I suppose, invoke a specific screenshot or prefs change from these parameters & save as an Applescript app or service.

You can't tweak the settings separately for each access method, though. As noted, they are alternative ways to invoke the same app.